# Can't delete folder XP Pro

Tags: windows-xp

No luck. I have 2 HDD. This folder on my second drive; f45bb07bdf4b29fdffb20c39e5 cannot be deleted. This second drive (D:) is strictly for storage and has no programs on it. Inside this folder, there are 90 files and 26 folders. It was recently created 12-29-16. This drive is not new. It has been in use for about a year. ...never had anything on it but what I put there. Checking 'Properties' does not tell me the company that created it. The folders inside the main one were created in 2013. Their names are simply numbers, 4 digits, plus one folder called 'Graphics'. ...tried everything. Not comfortable with it as I don't know what it is. When I updated Adobe, it turned on Automatic updates without my knowledge. I have removed all updates that sneaked in because I no longer trust Microsoft. File Assassin couldn't remove it either. Any ideas?

Comment: If it's the largest partition, Microsoft will use it to store updaters etc. [Not providing this as an answer, because I don't know the full details of how it works]

Comment: Did you try booting from a CD/Stick and try again?
These files are of windows update, see http://forums.computershopper.com/showthread.php?t=265
(maybe you should just leave them be)

Comment: `f45bb07bdf4b29fdffb20c39e5` is a Windows Update folder.  Why do you want to delete it?  Windows Update will place updates on the largest disk it discovers.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly what it is, but i think it is some kind of windows update folder. Try disabling windows update. If you want to remove this folder, try little program called Unlocker created by someone with the name Cedric collomb. or Iobit has its own unlocker program but for me it didn't worked so well. I recommend Unlocker.
*hope this helps